# Passing strings to bash functions with space

Tags: bash, quotes

I have a line which I have read from a file

```
line="1 \"Some Text Here\""
```

and a function which takes two arguments

```
print() {
    echo $1
    echo $2
}
```

When I execute

```
print $line
```

The output I get is

```
1
"Some
```

What I want to get is

```
1
Some Text Here
```

Comment: The file format seems to make a false assumption about how quotes work in `bash`. If possible, change the file to make `line` an array: `line=(1 "Some Text Here")`.

Comment: Would this make sence in the context of a line read from a file. Would be rather odd to have a file with lines in such a format, would drive excel crazy,

Comment: How are you defining the `bash` variable `line`? The line you show is not a valid `bash` assignment statement (the spaces around the equal sign are not allowed). I was assuming that it was a typo and you were simply sourcing the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you trust the input, you can use `eval` (normally to be avoided, as rogue input strings can do unwanted things):

```
line="1 \"Some Text Here\""
eval print "$line"          # `print` is the shell function from the question
```

Even with harmless input strings, however, the `eval` command will break if the input string contains so-called **shell metacharacters**: `| & ; ( ) < >`.

Also, if the string happens to contain tokens such as `*` that look like pathname patterns (globs), they would inadvertently get expanded; the relevant **pattern characters** are: `* ? [ ]`.

Thus, to make the above more robust, **escape pattern characters and metacharacters in the input string with `\`** as follows:

```
eval print "$(sed 's/[][*?&;()<>]/\\&/g' <<<"$line")"
```

---

**Update**: It turns out that there's **no need for `eval`**, after all: the problem **can be solved with `xargs`, which recognizes quoted substrings inside a string literal.**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Sample function that prints each argument passed to it separately
print() {
    for arg; do
      echo "[$arg]" # enclose value in [] to better see its boundaries
    done
}

# Sample input string with embedded quoted strings, an unqoted
# glob-like string, and an string containing shell metacharacters
line="1 \"double-quoted string\" * 'single-quoted string' string-with-;|>-(metachars)"

# Let `xargs` split the string into lines (-n 1) and read the
# result into a bash array (read -ra).
# This relies on `xargs`' ability to recognize quoted strings embedded
# in a string literal.
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra args <<<"$(xargs -n 1 printf '%s\n' <<<"$line")"

# Now pass the array to the `print` function.
print "${args[@]}"
```

Result:

```
[1]
[double-quoted string]
[*]
[single-quoted string]
[string-with-;|>-(metachars)]
```

**Notes and limitations**:

- *Unquoted* tokens allow use of `\` to escape embedded characters such as spaces, single and double quotes.

  - However, an `\` before *other* characters is *also* ignored, which can be undesired; e.g.: `echo 'a\b' | xargs # -> 'ab'` - either use `\\`, or single- or double-quote the token instead.
- *Quoted* tokens do not require interior `\`-escaping, but sadly, *do not support embedding quotes of the same type* - no escaping seems to work.
- Note that specifying `printf '%s\n'` as the command to execute by `xargs` is *typically* not necessary, because `xargs` defaults to invoking the `echo` utility (not the shell *builtin*); however, some `echo` implementations recognize *options of their own*, such as `-e` (while not supporting `--`), so that the first output token could be mistaken for an option.
  By contrast, `printf '%s\n` works in *all* situations.
- *Quoted* strings that have *embedded newlines* are *not supported*. (`xargs` reports a parsing error in that case) - presumably, this will rarely be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the variable `IFS`. In your script type `IFS=\"`. This should fix your problem .

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific situation, using `shift` might work for you.

For example:

```
print() {
    echo "$1"
    shift
    echo "$*"
}
```

This prints the first parameter, shift the parameter list (removing the first parameter), then prints the remaining parameters.

That should give you this result:

```
$ text="1 \"Multiple Words Here\""

$ print() {
>     echo "$1"
>     shift
>     echo "$*"
> }


$ print $text
1
"Multiple Words Here"
```